# set map center in leaflet with 3857 lat/lon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, projection, wms

I'm trying to set map center with lat/lon of 3857 projection in leaflet.
By using lat/lon of projection 4326 its working fine.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
    }).setView([51.40457186188496, -2.3741738081973844], 13);
```

But it dose not working if i provide 3857 lat/lon.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
        }).setView([6693172.2381477, -264291.81938326], 13);
```

Please help me where i am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet's API uses lat/lng for all its operations, so you should never use projected coordinates when calling Leaflet.

If you have projected coordinates, which strictly speaking *isn't latitude and longitude*, you can turn them into lat/lng by unprojecting them. Since current stable versions of Leaflet has a slightly different definition of EPSG:3857, you will have to divide your coordinate by the EPSG:3857's sphere radius. Also, your coordinate appears to have x and y swapped. Anyway, here's code to perform the conversion:

`function toLatLng(x, y, map) {
   var projected = L.point(y, x).divideBy(6378137);
   return map.options.crs.projection.unproject(projected);
}`

Call it like this:

`var latLng = toLatLng(6693172.2381477, -264291.81938326, myMap);`

You could also work with a library like Proj4js to do projection/unprojection: http://proj4js.org/

Comment: yes you right first i need to unprojected the point.but the method you mention its unprojected the point but not correctly. e.g(lat:-90, lng :383490520.79999435)

Comment: i don't want to use extra lib like Proj4js.